# Can you Ready a Help action against a creature not (currently) adjacent to you?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action

Per the combat rules,

> Alternatively, you can aid a friendly creature in attacking a creature within 5 feet of you.

Is there anything in the rules that prevents me from readying an action to help one specific creature (Friend) attack another (Enemy), should at some point before my next turn Enemy find itself within 5ft of me?

Comment: Could you provide an example when it matters?

Comment: @enkryptor familiar sitting on my shoulder readies an action to help me attack a dude I intend to approach on my turn. Which was explicit in my previous question before it was locked.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be better to reopen the former question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168247/

Comment: @enkryptor I decided to narrow down the scope instead.

Comment: I think it became broader instead. A PC being able to ready Help action doesn't automatically mean a familiar can mount a PC and give them a permanent advantage. You also might be interested in this Q https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159986/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### I don't see why not

Ready action says:

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

Your trigger might be something like *when enemy gets close and is being attacked by my friend*. And the action you would choose is the *help* action.

When (or if) that trigger happens, you can execute the action that you've chosen – if it is possible.